# laravel 4 get controller method from route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

if I have a simple route

```
Route::get('foo', 'path\to\controller\MyController@bar');
```

when I'm in my application - Is there a method/function that will return the controller method that was used?  ie:  `bar`

.... is there anything like `\Route::getCurrentControllerMethod()`

Answer (score 3):

In case you only want get `bar` from your current Route, you should use:

```
$method = explode('@', Route::currentRouteAction());
$method = end ($method);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction();
Route::currentRouteAction();
Route::currentRouteName();
```

http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10095